# Why writing access error to /storage/logs directory after git pull command

Tags: laravel, git

When I pull updates of my Laravel 5.7 app on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS(Digital Ocean)
with command

```
sudo git pull origin master
```

I need next to run command

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/the-project/storage
```

otherwize I got writing access error to app/storage/logs directory. Is it .gitignore misconfiguration ?
I have

```
cat .gitignore
/node_modules
/public/hot
/public/storage
/storage/*.key
/vendor
/.idea

.env
.phpunit.result.cache
Homestead.json
Homestead.yaml
npm-debug.log
yarn-error.log

composer.lock
package-lock.json
```

?

Thanks!

Comment: You're pulling the code with `sudo` which means the code will belong to root. You must be running as root to be able to write to folders in this case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I think whole storage should be gitignored.
Everytime you pull your branch it overwrites existing storage, hance the permission issues.

Answer (score 1):

it mostly occurs when

1. you are working on windows and your server is linux based
2. when you have linux and other develop push changes from windows

There is one command that i use

`git config core.fileMode false`

This does not detect file modified change when you change permissions